# Boost::graph Dijkstra : initially populating the queue

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra, boost-graph

I'm using `boost::graph` and its Dijkstra implementation.

I want to compute THE shortest path from a set of vertices to another set of vertices.
I do not want to compute all the possible paths between those sets.

The idea is the following : I'm in a building with entrances on various streets. So I can start my journey on any of those streets. But I'm only interested in the shortest one.

If I had used my own implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm, I would have done the following:

- For each start node, the distance map to 0
- Add the start node to the priority queue.

While it's easy to set the distance map to 0 using `boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths_no_init`, I cannot figure out how to add the node to the priority queue.
I looked into the source code, and it seems pretty much impossible.
So I'm thinking of defining my own Combine functor that will return a 0 distance if I reach one of the start nodes, but it seems rather ugly.

I could create a virtual node, and add edges from the virtual node to starting nodes. However, this triggers some concurrent access problems I would like to avoid.

Did I miss a possibility in the boost library, or does someone know of a clever workaround. I'm also thinking of patching boost to allow a custom initialization of the priority queue.

Comment: None of the major "shortest path" algorithms compute "all the possible paths"  They compute only a shortest path.  Dijkstra's algorithm has to compute a shortest path from a single node to every-other node in a graph as part of its nature.  It's not doing any extra work.

Comment: And I do *not* want to compute all the possible paths (but algorithms exist like Floyd–Warshall's). There is nothing wrong with stuffing the priority queue with multiple departure points; the behaviour is the same as if you had null cost edges from your virtual to the starting nodes)

Comment: Floyd–Warshal's doesn't compute "all possible paths". It computes a shortest path for all-pairs of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used boost::graph, and I hope somebody with better knowledge of it will give a better answer, but perhaps you could create a graph type that wraps the existing graph, leaving the original unmodified, but exposing to the algorithm a view that includes your virtual nodes and edges? If not, is it infeasible to copy the whole graph?

Comment: The graph is the Paris area, with 1,5M edges. So I cannot afford to copy it. However your idea is not bad. I have to see how much pain it is to implement it in boost::graph :)

Comment: @Tristram, this comment confused me on the question. What do you mean you cant copy it? I dont quite get the problem either, is it that your graph is too big to traverse at once?

Comment: Traversing the graph is no problem, it's a about 10ms (paths are small compared to the whole graph). However copying the graph will consume to much memory and time (the application is a webservice) to be acceptable. Computing 10 times dijkstra will be more acceptable in terms of time

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't copy it. Just wrap it in something that will add a virtual vertex. Though the additional requirements of the dijkstra implementation don't make it easy.